# How to use LabelFor in MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.updateDate)
```

but this is transformed into `<label for="updateDate">updateDate</label>` and the value is not displayed just updateDate.
How can I display the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `DisplayFor` instead of `LabelFor`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.updateDate)
```

Comment: I'm sure it works! But can you give me a solution for Label? thanks

Comment: You can use `@Html.Label(Model.updateDate.ToString())` if you like

Comment: and also attach a @Html.HiddenField? I think it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

A small issue with DisplayFor.
 If you load the value from a JS operation, you need to add a span with an id to modify its value .